# Ionic events for global nav

Tags: angular, events, ionic-framework

I am in ionic 3 and would like to simplify my navigation a lot. The nav is pulled from a JSON feed. I did have it running in one page and returning data within that page and using that data to build the nav in that view. So I now have it running in the app.components.ts file like this

In constructor:

```
events.subscribe('menu:getMenu', () => {
  this.getMenuStatic();
});
```

and then the function still in app.components.ts

```
getMenuStatic() {

  --JSON ARRAY/CODE IN HERE--

  var JSONObject = menuData.data;
  this.menuItems = JSONObject;
}
```

but I can't seem to think and understand how I would access this.menuItems in every page in my app, so therefore using its data to build my nav 'globally' in every page. I'm thinking it would be something along the lines of

```
events.publish('menu:getMenu')
events.subscribe('menu:getMenu')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We don't know what modules you declare or your app structure, but if you say you build the menu in every page, you can use a service for that. It doesn't need to work with events, the service initializes with the menu in `menuItems`, and can be injected in all pages.

Comment: Kaddath, that got me learning about REST API's and way's to 'include' and pull data from one central source. So a bit of restructuring has enable me to group some app specific functions in a rest.ts file and I can now run those from any page in the app, reducing code duplication. Many Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help